# Cannot import module in script when fed to manage.py

Tags: python, django, shell

I have a script that defines a function and then runs it

```
from datetime import timedelta

def foo():
    return timedelta(days=2)


print(foo())
```

If I open a shell and run the script, everything runs fine:

```
./manage.py shell

In [1]: %run web/the_script.py # Using Ipython
2 days, 0:00:00
```

But when I run the script as input for `./manage.py shell` (I want to run the script as a `cron` job) it fails like this:

```
./manage.py shell < the_script.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/satan/Development/envs/p3_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/satan/Development/envs/p3_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 355, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/satan/Development/envs/p3_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 283, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/satan/Development/envs/p3_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 330, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/satan/Development/envs/p3_env/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/shell.py", line 101, in handle
    exec(sys.stdin.read())
  File "<string>", line 8, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in foo
NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined
```

Can someone explain what is happening please?

Comment: @Cyzanfar No. I did it, ran the script again, and it failed again.

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: @Cyzanfar Python 3, with Django 1.11.2

Comment: ok try `sudo pip3 install datetime`

Comment: @Cyzanfar I am running all of this in a `virtualenv`, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: Oh i see thanks for that precision

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this issue before where it sometimes only executes the first line( or the first function) from the script. It basically is because the functions do not stay defined (or the imports in your case) throughout the execution of the script.

Try this:

```
./manage.py shell <<EOF\ execfile(the_script.py') \EOF
```

or, if it's Python 3+

```
$ ./manage.py shell
...

>>> exec(open('./myscript.py').read())
```

Not so good solution:

```
echo 'import the_script' | python manage.py shell
```